# Is it possible for {proxy+} to capture "/" in API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to set up a basic reverse-proxy from `http://foo.com` to `http://foo.internal:38121` using API Gateway (so I don't have to get involved w/ deploying NGINX clusters).

I cannot just use CloudFront -> `http://foo.internal:38121` without API Gateway, since I need to change `http://foo.internal:38121` to something else on each deploy... and changing the CloudFront origin would trigger an untenable ~40 minute update. Furthermore, I cannot used fixed ports (so CloudFront w/ fixed origin and a DNS change per-deploy is also not an option)... something needs to be able to *instantly* map `foo.com:80` onto `foo.internal:???`.

I'm attempting to use API Gateway:

```
/
  /{proxy+}
  ANY
```

However, the endpoint produces this:

```
> curl https://XYZ.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/
{ "message": "Missing Authentication Token" }
```

Whereas this works:

```
> curl https://XYZ.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/hello_world/
Hello!
```

I can workaround the issue by adding a secondary `ANY` method:

```
/
ANY
  /{proxy+}
  ANY
```

Which fixes it:

```
> curl https://XYZ.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/
Hello!
```

**However** the duplicate config for each deployment is not ideal.

For example: it could produce a bug. Although deployments occur atomically, "staging" the changes does not. This means there's a risk whereby 2 concurrent CI builds could update `/` and `/.+` to point to a new upstream (e.g. with `aws apigateway update-integration` x2 -- one for each resource), but as the `4x` total commands overlap from the `2x` concurrent CI builds, the methods could end up pointing to different upstreams, and subsequently get deployed.

Is it possible for `{proxy+}` to capture `/` in API Gateway? (Or is there a simpler/better way to achieve this style of reverse-proxying w/ instant-ish upstream changes, just using AWS components?)

Comment: This is a very old known bug in APIG (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=749625).  Best best for now is probably cloudformation templates to manage the duplication.